# Errors in measurement of Input offset voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, circuit-analysis, analog, input-offset-voltage

I am reading AD application note [MT-037](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-037.pdf) for input offset voltage measurement procedure.

App note says , measurement will have small error induced due to input bias current .

"For example, 2 nA bias current flowing through the 10 Ω resistor
produces a 0.02 µV error referred to the input"

[image]

My question is, if the source resistances seen (10||10k) are same for both inverting and non inverting terminal then 2 nA bias currents will generate same common mode voltages (0.02 µV) at inverting and non inverting terminal and eventually get cancelled (CMRR=∞, no mention of CMRR value in app note), then how would they create error in offset measurement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how would they create error in offset measurement?*

We talk about two types of input current usually: -

- Input **bias** current (same for both inputs)
- Input **offset** current (difference in bias current between the two inputs

So, we can solve the input **bias** current problem by keeping the resistors associated with each input the same but, we can't solve input **offset** current problems other than by keeping the net resistance at each input low.

Comment: So 2nA is actually 'input offset current' and not 'input bias current' in application note ? it then makes sense as different voltages are generated due to different bias currents values  creaing differential mode voltage.

Comment: I can't help you there because I don't know what you are referring to. I can say that if they say "**bias** current" then they *should* mean what I described in my answer but, there's no way I can tell if they made a typo.